# Unable to export or encrypt the private key for Google Play App Signing

Tags: java, android, google-play

I'm trying to **EXPORT AND ENCRYPT PRIVATE KEY to enroll into Google Play App Signing**

I followed the template:

```
$ java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=encrypted_private_key_path --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a
```

and it worked for 2 other apps without any issues, but there is another application called mods that keeps throwing the following error even though **I'm able to generate APKs with this jks file** just fine:

```
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=mods.jks --alias=my_alias_here --output=encrypted_private_key --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a
```

```
**Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect**
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:813)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:226)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1503)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.KeystoreHelper.loadKeystore(KeystoreHelper.java:53)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.KeystoreHelper.getKeystore(KeystoreHelper.java:39)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.run(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:207)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.main(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:165)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:811)
    ... 6 more
```

I tried

```
Keytool -list -keystore mods.jks
```

and realized that the password for the keystore is nothing, i pressed enter and I got to see SHA key